# free web hosting for lamp stack web server with php mail() support

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, lamp

Hi I'm new beginner here working on raspberry pi lamp web server I'm looking for suggestions that can help me about free web hosting on lamp web that support a function php mail()